# JQUERY Photo Popup Text

Tags: jquery

Looking for some direction/advice...

I have members photos on a site and I want to have text information popup on the bottom part of the image regarding the member - say age, location etc.

It would need to cover the photo but have opacity so it doesn't blockout the image.

Any advice on how to pursue this?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any JavaScript for doing this. You can use CSS :hover state to show info on mouse hover the image.
Say you have a markup like this:

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="overlay">
    Name: John
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can write a css like this:

```
.image{position:relative;}
  .overlay{position:absolute; bottom:0; display:none;}
  .overlay:hover{display:block;}
```

then for having opacity in all browsers it's better not using css opacity because it's not supported in old browser. I would use a single pixel png that have alpha less than 1.